# Первод данных типа bytes в тип float

Tags: python

Имеется файл, в каждой строке которого хранятся данные типа byte. Необходимо считать файл и перевести строки в float. У меня считывает первую строку, а в остальных случаях он выдаёт 0. Как считать все строчки и записать их в массив X? Насчёт функции `np.frombuffer` я не уверен

```
X = np.zeros(N)
for c in range(N):
    Clinex = file.readline()[5:13]
    X[c] = np.frombuffer(ClineX, dtype = np.float64)
```

Comment: Вы читаете файл построчно. Но если там записаны байты, а не текст, то откуда там переводы строки? Наверное, у вас читается сразу весь файл как одна строка. Определитесь, что вы читаете. Если байты, то читайте через `read` с указанием числа байт, которое считываете за один раз. Ну и режим чтения файла не забудьте выставить тот, который используете по факту.

Comment: Ну даже если читать посимвольно, то он считывает только 1 строку

Comment: Файл двоичный или текстовый? Двоичный файл нужно открывать в двоичном режиме `"rb"` и читать данные через `read`, а не через `readline`. В двоичном файле нет никаких строк.

Comment: Это txt файл, открытый через `rb`. Внутри 5 строк.  Одна из них это.  
 `b'PV02E\x90'` и т.д.

Comment: Двоичный файл нужно читать по позициям, он не читается по строкам

Comment: Ну тут даже если считать по позициям, то он все-равно выводит только значение на первой итерации

Comment: "даже если считать по позициям," - как только догадаемся, какой именно код у вас "считает по позициям", то поможем. Может быть.

Comment: Ну и заголовок тут не отражает вопроса. Проблема у вас с чтением бинарных данных из файла, а не с их переводом в число.

Answer (score 0):

не стоит пренебрегать функцией frombuffer:

```
import numpy as np
 
X = np.frombuffer(b"\x00\x00\x86\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdeB", dtype=np.float32)
print(X)

output(X)
>>>[-67.   0. 111.]
```

как я понимаю, это решение вашей проблемы